# why my database does not update ? (LARAVEL)

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

my database does not update while when i do

```
 dd(request()->has('validated'));
```

this is what my web.php looks like:

```
Route::patch('prof/theme/{id}/validated', 'Theme\ThemeController@valide')->name('prof.theme.validated');
```

this is what my ThemeController.php looks like:

```
public function valide(Theme $theme) {
        $theme->update([
            'validated' => request()->has('validated')
        ]);
       return back();

    }
```

this is what my show.blade.php looks like:

```
<form action="{{route('prof.theme.validated', $theme)}}" method="POST">
                        @csrf
                        @method('PATCH')
                             @if ($theme->validated)
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger text-center" style="width: 350px">
                                            INVALIDER LE THEME
                                </button>
                             @else
                                 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success text-center" name="validated" id="validated" style="width: 350px">
                                                VALIDER LE THEME
                                 </button>
                             @endif
                         </form>
```

this code does not show me any error but it does not produce the expected action. my variable "validated" is a boolean

Comment: change your route 'prof/theme/{id}/validated' to 'prof/theme/{theme}/validated', check route model binding https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/routing#route-model-binding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thank you Harshith VA!!!!! i was able to solve the problem thanks to your idea. I kept your view and used your controller idea this way

```
public function valide(Request $request, Theme $theme) {

        $theme->validated = $request->has('validated');
        $theme->save();
       return back();

    }
```

thanks you for your help

Answer (score 0):

From first look, I would believe this is due to the fact that you have added `name="validated"` to the `<button>` and not as an `<input>`.

```php
<form action="{{route('prof.theme.validated', $theme)}}" method="POST">
    @csrf
    @method('PATCH')
     @if ($theme->validated)
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger text-center" style="width: 350px">
                    INVALIDER LE THEME
        </button>
     @else
         <input type="hidden" name="validated" value="true"> 
         <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success text-center" style="width: 350px">
                        VALIDER LE THEME
         </button>
     @endif
 </form>
```

Here, we add a hidden input field with the `validated` input. Doing this should pass that the `validated` key/value to the controller.

Another point. `dd()` is used to die and dump data, and would stop execution of whatever script is running. Therefore it won't save to the db once you do this.

The above assumes you didn't mean it doesn't save to the database when you `dd()`.

#### Update

Also note that `->has()` checks if the input exists. You should use `request('validated')` to get its value.

Comment: I tried what you recommended but the values ​​remain unchanged.